# Shortcodes in Options Panel textareas

Tags: shortcode

I am using an Options Panel to create my themes, and I would like to make the textareas from this OP to support my shortcodes too.

The code for that creates the textarea fields:

```
case 'textarea':
            $cols = '8';
            $ta_value = '';

            if(isset($value['options'])) {
                    $ta_options = $value['options'];
                    if(isset($ta_options['cols'])) {
                    $cols = $ta_options['cols'];
                    } 
                }

                $ta_value = stripslashes($data[$value['id']]);

                $output .= '<textarea class="of-input" name="'.$value['id'].'" id="'. $value['id'] .'" cols="'. $cols .'" rows="8">'.$ta_value.'</textarea>';
        break;
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Please let me know if I should provide more details.
Thanks.

Comment: simply use `echo do_shortcode($textarea_value);`

Comment: Yes, this works. I was looking more for a solution to wrap the textarea in do_shortcode() , so I don't add do_shortcode() to all my $textarea_value(s). But I will go with your solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Bogh, can you post your corrected code here as an Answer? So this question doesn't remain *unanswered*...  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use `echo do_shortcode($textarea_value);` (answer by @Bainternet)

Comment: Why not mark it as the answer?